# tinymce-rails set content_css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, tinymce

I'm developing an Rails application and using the tinymce-rails gem. In the TinyMce configuration I can normally set my main `content.css` file that is used by the editor, so it looks like the result while editing.

For my production environment I can set the `content_css` parameter to `application.css` because that is the only css file after `asset:precompile`, is there any trick to get the same functionality in my development environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

does this work for you? `content_css: '<%= asset_path 'application.css' %>'`

Comment: I can't do this in the yml file but when I call tinymce I can pass `asset_path 'application.css'` as parameter and it works great, thanks a lot.

Comment: how do you pass it as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me...

When instantiating TinyMCE in my view, I pass in `content_css` as an option to the `tinymce` method:

```
<%= tinymce content_css: asset_path('application.css') %>
```